# Php for each loop double result

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and trying to build a web app.
This *foreach* loop outputs two results in two separate rows instead of one in the following table cell element (i.e. *td*):

```
 <td><?=$item['title'];?></td>
    <td><?=$item['category'];?></td>
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
      $iQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE deleted = 0");
      $lowItems = array();
        while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($iQuery)){
                $item = array();
                $sizes = sizesToArray($product['sizes']);
                foreach($sizes as $size){
                    if ($size['quantity'] <= $size['threshold']) {
                        $cat = get_category($product['categories']);
                        $item = array(
                            'title' => $product['title'],
                            'size' => $size['size'],
                            'quantity' => $size['quantity'],
                            'threshold' => $size['threshold'],
                            'category' => $cat['parent'] . ' ~ ' .$cat['child']
                        );
                        $lowItems[] = $item;
                    }
                }
        }

    ?>

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <h3 class="text-center">Low Stock</h3>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Threshold</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($lowItems as $item): ?>
            <tr<?=($item['quantity'] == 0)?' class="danger"':'';?>>
                <td><?=$item['title'];?></td>
                <td><?=$item['category'];?></td>
                <td><?=$item['size'];?></td>
                <td><?=$item['quantity'];?></td>
                <td><?=$item['threshold'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The rest of the table cells are showing only once - just two first ones are being repeated twice.

#### sizes to Array function:

```
function sizesToArray($string){
    $sizesArray = explode(',', $string);
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($sizesArray as $size){
        $s = explode(':',$size);
        $returnArray[] = array('size' => $s[0], 'quantity' => $s[1],'threshold' => $s[2]);
    }
    return $returnArray;    
}
```

And here is var dump of $LowItems:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> array(5) {
        ["title"]=> string(6) "Tshirt"
        ["size"]=> string(5) "Small"
        ["quantity"]=> string(1) "2"
        ["threshold"]=> string(1) "5"
        ["category"]=> string(12) "Men ~ Shirts"
    }
    [1]=> array(5) {
        ["title"]=> string(6) "Tshirt"
        ["size"]=> string(0) ""
        ["quantity"]=> NULL
        ["threshold"]=> NULL
        ["category"]=> string(12) "Men ~ Shirts"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to var_dump `$lowItems`? Did you check HTML generated?

Comment: What is `sizesToArray()`

Comment: Hey I updated and included sizes to array function , Have a look

Comment: @E_p Hey i included var dump please have a look

Comment: As I suspected you have a duplicate row that has all the data empty except for title and category. Happy debugging ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ($size['quantity'] <= $size['threshold']) {
```

To

```
if ($size['size'] && $size['quantity'] <= $size['threshold']) {
```

Comment: Works like a charm, Thank you , You are a super star :)

Comment: @Comunit3 It kind of just hides error. You need to find out where it comes from.

Comment: Indeed I'll a have look in this but your answer solved my problem .